# Mi lista no se actualiza a menos que cierre y abra la app SwiftUI

Tags: lista, swift, swiftui

Cree una app que guarda ejercicios de gym, generando una lista, tengo2 vistas, en la primera solo quiero mostrar los ejercicios, la segunda es para crear el ejercicio con sus datos, pero cuando los creo la primera vista no se me actualiza a no ser que abra y cierre la app.
lo hice con un tutoría que utiliz Json para guardar los ejercicios! Muchas gracias

View donde creo el ejercicio:

```
@ObservedObject var EjerViewModel = ejerViewModel()


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            VStack{
                VStack() {
                    Text("Agrega tu ejercicio")
                        .bold()
                }
                .frame(width:300,alignment: .leading)
                
                TextField("Ejercicio", text: $nombre)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300,height: 50)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                TextField("Descripcion", text: $descripcion)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300,height: 50)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    

                    .padding()
                VStack {
                    Text("Carga tus pesos")
                        .padding(1)
                    .font(.headline)
                }
                .frame(width:300,alignment: .leading)
                
                HStack{
                    VStack {
                        TextField("KG", text:$rm1)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 50)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(5)
                    Text("1 rep max")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .padding(2)
                    
                    VStack {
                        TextField("KG", text:$rm2)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 50)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(5)
                    Text("2 rep max")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .padding(2)
            
                    VStack {
                        TextField("KG", text:$rm3)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 50)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(5)
                    Text("3 rep max")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .padding(2)
                    
                    VStack {
                        TextField("KG", text:$rm4)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 50)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(5)
                    Text("10 rep max")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .padding(2)
  
                }
                Button("Crear ejercicio"){
                    EjerViewModel.saveEjerc(nombre: nombre, descripcion: descripcion, rep1: rm1, rep2: rm2,rep3: rm3,rep4: rm4)
                    nombre = ""
                    
                }
                .frame(width: 350,height: 50)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .bold()
                    .cornerRadius(60)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                
                
                     List{
                         ForEach(EjerViewModel.ejercicios,id: \.id) {ejer in
                             HStack{
                                 Text(ejer.nombre)
                                     
                             }
                             
                         }
                       
                     }
            }            
    }
    
}
```

}

view donde quiero mostrar mi lista  :

```
@ObservedObject var EjerViewModel : ejerViewModel 

var body: some View {
   NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Form{
                Spacer()
                List{
                    ForEach($EjerViewModel.ejercicios,id: \.id) {$ejer in
                        HStack{
                            Text(ejer.nombre)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(ejer.rep1) KG")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                        
                        .frame(height:20)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                            Button {
                                EjerViewModel.removeejer(withId: ejer.id)
                            } label: {
                                Label("borrar", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                            }
                            .tint(.red) // pintar el recuadrito para borrar
                            
                        }
                    }

                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .padding()
            }
            NavigationLink(destination:AgregarEjerView(EjerViewModel: ejerViewModel())){
                Text("Agregar ejercicio nuevo")
            }
            .frame(width: 350,height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Ejercicios")
        
        
    }
}
```

}
alguno sabe alguna solución para este problema? ya busque por todos lados jaja

Comment: Podemos ver el modelo para tu ejercicio? y el view model?

Comment: Hola, lo solucione directamente creando mi app con firebase, muchas gracias por tu comentario !